# How to get line number when an exception occurs for release version of flash application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am trying to get line number of exceptions for an released version of flash application(Flex based). 
I have followed below instructions, but could not get the line number information.
http://technobytz.com/setting-compiler-options-in-flash-builder.html
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html

My Flash Builder compiler setting:
[image: flash builder setting]

The exception stack trace information of release version:
[image: exception stack trace without line number]

Comment: `CONFIG::debug = true`?

Comment: I need to support this with release version. Not debug one.

Comment: I always compile an release version AND an additional debug version. In case of a problem I can switch the application to the debug version to trace errors.

Answer (score 2):

No way

so what would be difference between debug and release! there is no compile command for it! its not about compile,  also its not about flash builder! only **debug** version of flash supports this feature

from [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html#getStackTrace())

> The preceding listing shows the value of this method when called in a debugger version of Flash Player or code running in the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL). **When code runs in a release version of Flash Player or AIR, the stack trace is provided without the file path and line number information**, <del>as in the following example:</del>

be happy of getting error messages in release version even without Line number.